When the timer runs out, the question that should be asked does not appear
This some specific part of the code in C# form is not working. Same method (ShowQuestion()) is working for everywhere else. But when the time is finish and the next question must come to the screen it don't. Help me out please. I've tried asking ChatGPT, did some resarch but no couldn't find a solution.
I have tried CustomTimeBox change to MessageBox but didn't work either.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace QuizApp
{
    public partial class formGame : Form
    {

        private List<Question> questions;
        private int questionIndex = 0;
        private int countCorrect = 0;
        private int countIncorrect = 0;
        private Timer timer;
        private int time = 25;

        public formGame()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CreateQuestions();
            ShowQuestion();
            StartTimer();
        }

        private void StartTimer()
        {
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CustomTimeBox customTimeBox = new CustomTimeBox();
            time -= 1;
            lblTimer.Text = $"Kalan süre: {time} saniye";
            if (time == 0)
            {
                timer.Stop();
                if (customTimeBox.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    ShowQuestion();
                }
            }
        }

        private void CreateQuestions()
        {
            questions = new List<Question>
            {
                new Question("Hangi gezegen Güneş Sistemi'ndeki en büyük gezegendir?", "Jüpiter", new List<string>{"Jüpiter", "Mars", "Venüs", "Neptün"}),
                new Question("Mona Lisa'nın tablosunun yaratıcısı kimdir?", "Leonardo da Vinci", new List<string>{ "Leonardo da Vinci", "Pablo Picasso", "Vincent van Gogh", "Michelangelo"}),
                new Question("Hangi ülkenin bayrağında beyaz bir zambak çiçeği bulunur?", "Hollanda", new List<string>{ "Kanada", "Japonya", "Fransa", "Hollanda"}),
            };
        }

        private void ShowQuestion()
        {
            time = 2;
            lblTimer.Text = $"Kalan süre: {time} saniye";
            if (questionIndex < questions.Count)
            {
                lblQuestions.Text = questions[questionIndex].QuestionText;
                btnA.Text = questions[questionIndex].Options[0];
                btnB.Text = questions[questionIndex].Options[1];
                btnC.Text = questions[questionIndex].Options[2];
                btnD.Text = questions[questionIndex].Options[3];
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Quiz bitti! Toplam soru:{questions.Count}\nDoğru sayısı: {countCorrect}\nYanlış sayısı: {countIncorrect}");
            }
            
        }



        private void MinimizeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }

        private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CustomCloseBox customCloseBox = new CustomCloseBox();
            if (customCloseBox.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
            
        }

        public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
        public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;
        [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

        private void moveableBar_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                ReleaseCapture();
                SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, (IntPtr)HT_CAPTION, (IntPtr)0);
            }
        }

        private void btnA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            string answer = btnA.Text;
            if (questions[questionIndex].IsRightAnswer(answer))
            {
                countCorrect++;
            }
            else
            {
                countIncorrect++;
            }
            questionIndex++;
            ShowQuestion();
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void btnB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            string answer = btnB.Text;
            if (questions[questionIndex].IsRightAnswer(answer))
            {
                countCorrect++;
            }
            else
            {
                countIncorrect++;
            }
            questionIndex++;
            ShowQuestion();
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void btnC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            string answer = btnC.Text;
            if (questions[questionIndex].IsRightAnswer(answer))
            {
                countCorrect++;
            }
            else
            {
                countIncorrect++;
            }
            questionIndex++;
            ShowQuestion();
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void btnD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            string answer = btnD.Text;
            if (questions[questionIndex].IsRightAnswer(answer))
            {
                countCorrect++;
            }
            else
            {
                countIncorrect++;
            }
            questionIndex++;
            ShowQuestion();
            timer.Start();
        }
    }

    public class Question
    {
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
        public string RightAnswer { get; set; }
        public List<string> Options { get; set; }

        public Question(string questionText, string rightAnswer, List<string> options)
        {
            QuestionText = questionText;
            RightAnswer = rightAnswer;
            Options = new List<string>(options);
        }

        public void AddOption(string option)
        {
            Options.Add(option);
        }

        public bool IsRightAnswer(string answer)
        {
            return answer == RightAnswer;
        }
    }
}


This is the whole code and below here is the where is the problem
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CustomTimeBox customTimeBox = new CustomTimeBox();
    time -= 1;
    lblTimer.Text = $"Kalan süre: {time} saniye";
    if (time == 0)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        if (customTimeBox.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ShowQuestion();
        }
    }
}


When the time expires, you should increment the current question's index and restart the timer, after the notification -- BTW, you have set time = 2; in ShowQuestion() -- You can DRY up your code quite a lot. For example, you just need one Click event handler for all the Buttons

... and don't CustomTimeBox customTimeBox = new CustomTimeBox(); on every tick.  Only when you need it.
